# Leave or leaves in "you don't want to see your little bird leave the nest"

Tags: verbs, present-tense, to-infinitive

I was watching an episode of big bang theory and someone told his mother
"you don't want to see your little bird leave the nest".
Why he didn't say leaves?

Comment: *Your little bird* is not the subject of *leave*, but instead the object of *see*.

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but I think that verb "See" uses bare infinitive when it takes an object and to infinitive. So it's like this:

> you don't want to see your little bird (to) leave the nest.

But to is not shown, and is not supposed to be shown, because it's bare infinitive.

http://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive/ Something information about bare infinitive

Comment: +1 [After verbs of perception](http://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive)...

Answer (score 0):

After verbs like see, feel, hear, .... ( verbs related to senses) you can use either a **Verb+ing** or a **bare infinitive**. The latter implies a completed action and the former implies an action which was(is) in progress. compare:

> I saw him climbing the wall

This means the observer saw the process of the climbing, but it does not mean the observer saw the whole process.

> I saw him climb the wall

This means the observer saw a completed process, from start to end, in which the climber climbed the wall successfully.